# Why does Chrome developer tools sometimes not show a CSS source?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

Why does Chrome Developer Tools bottom right hand corner sometimes show a triangle against the CSS source (indicating - if you click on it - the CSS source) as in **width** in my screenshot ...

but sometimes not ... as in **height**  in my screenshot.

In other words, how can I tell what is setting height=575px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in that case the element does not have a specified css height that is being applied to it. It is being computed by the browser based on the size of something that it is contained in such as a container div, the browser window, etc.

Comment: thanks. is there any feature in Chrome's developer tools (or any other browser) which will show how this is being determined?

Comment: I don't know of any way to see that. A good example of why it would be so hard is looking at the code for your comment. There's a 'span.comment-copy' surrounded by a 'div'. To compute the div height, it takes into consideration the height of the span. On my screen I see your comment as two lines, so the height is 34px (two lines, line-height 17px). I'm not sure there's any straight-forward way for the dev tools to describe that, but if there is hopefully somebody has or will figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You have the "Computed" Tab selected there which means that Chrome will tell you the computed size of all of the parts. This means that what you see there isn't all explicitly set by a css file and may be derived by the element's contents.

If you wish to see only provided css style select the "Style" tab at the top of the window.

Comment: thanks. is there any feature in Chrome's developer tools (or any other browser) which will show how the "derived" setting is being determined?

Comment: I don't believe so. it's really just up to you to look at the internal elements and see what the heights add up to etc. Why is this so important to you? as you might be taking the wrong approach to solving you problem

Comment: important because i've got two very similar pages, one with the height set correctly and the other not. it turned out to be as you and the other answer explained, the height is being derived from other parent elements

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and I landed on this page, after some poking around I realised that because my css source file had been minified, dev tools wasn't able to detect the line as there was just one line obviously, so this might have been the cause of your issue as well.